# $\int\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+3}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's the process which I tried:

Let substitution: Substitute $x^{2} = t$. This creates a new variable $t$ and relates it to $x$ through differentiation ($2x dx = dt$).

Adjust the integral: Rewrite the integral in terms of $t$ using the substitution and $dt$.

Solve the resulting integral: This may involve factoring the denominator or using other techniques for integrating rational functions.

Substitute back: Replace $t$ with its original definition ($x^{2}$) to obtain the antiderivative in terms of $x

Comment: Unfortunately, because 2x is not present in the integrand, this substitution will not get you very far.  This is actually quite a difficult integral to do!

Comment: The denominator factors into complex polynomials.  $(x^2+1+i \sqrt2)(x^2+1-i \sqrt2)$  I'm guessing from there apply partial fraction decomposition.
Typically, variations with $(a+bx^2)$ in the denominator become integrate into a form of arctan.  However, you'll need someone more familiar with nonreal integration than I am to finish.

Comment: You might also try introducing $\frac{x}{x} $ and applying a variation of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320671/integrating-int-fracdx-sqrtx-1-x2?rq=1 using the substition $u=x^2$

Comment: Duplicate question, same OP
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889874/calculating-int-frac1x22x3-sqrtx-dx?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating $\int\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x}}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889874/calculating-int-frac1x22x3-sqrtx-dx)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{x^4-5x^2+16}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186356/evaluation-of-int-frac1x4-5x216dx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a systematic approach to the problems of integrating $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial. That is to factor $p(x)$ as a product of linear and quadratic polynomials, and then rewrite $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ as a sum of partial fractions. You can find the technique in any decent calculus textbook.

For this problem, first $$\begin{align}x^4+2x^2+3 &= (x^4+2\sqrt 3 x^2 + 3) - (2 \sqrt 3 - 2)x^2 \\ &= (x^2+\sqrt 3)^2 - (\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}x)^2 \\ &=(x^2+\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2 \sqrt{\sqrt 3 -1 } x)(x^2+\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2 \sqrt{\sqrt 3 -1 } x)\end{align}$$

We can check that both quadratic terms are positive definite and hence cannot be further factored (Indeed, $x^4+2x^2+3= (x^2+1)^2+2\ge 2$ has no real root, hence no linear factor over $\mathbb R$. Actually this seems to be an easier approach to factor the polynomial, but it's a trap as it will involve complex numbers. Even [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%201%2F%28x%5E4%2B2x%5E2%2B3%29) gets confused.)

For simlicity of notation, let's denote $a=\sqrt 3, b=\sqrt 2 \sqrt{\sqrt 3 -1 }$.

Then let $$\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+3}=\frac{1}{(x^2+bx+a)(x^2-bx+a)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-bx+a} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2+bx+a}$$

Now we can find $A, B, C, D$ in terms of $a, b$, and then we have to complete the squares $$(x^2\pm bx+a)=(x\pm \frac{b}{2})^2 + (a-\frac{b^2}{4})$$

It's all standard but lots of computations. I'll leave to those who have more patience.

Comment: How about $\displaystyle\left(\sqrt{2}\left(-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\left(\sqrt{3}+3\right)\left(\log\left(\sqrt{3}+x^2-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\sqrt{2}x\right)-\log\left(\sqrt{3}+x^2+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\sqrt{2}x\right)\right)+2\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\sqrt{2}-2x}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}\sqrt{2}}\right)-2\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}\left(\sqrt{3}-3\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\sqrt{2}+2x}{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right)/48$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+3}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left({\frac{\sqrt{3}-x^2}{x^4+2x^2+3}+\frac{x^2+\sqrt{3}}{x^4+2x^2+3}}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left({\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}-1}{\left({x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2-2\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}+1}{\left({x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{3}}}\right)$$

Therfore:
$$\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+3}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(f(x) + g(x))$$
Where :
$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}-1}{\left({x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2-2\sqrt{3}}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}+1}{\left({x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{3}}$$

we have :
$$F(x)=\int  \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}-1}{\left({x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2-2\sqrt{3}} dx$$
Let $u:=x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}$
$$F(x)=-\int \frac{du}{u^2-(2\sqrt{3}-2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-2}}\tanh^{-1}\left({\frac{u}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-2}}}\right)$$
therfore:
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-2}}\tanh^{-1}\left({\frac{x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-2}}}\right)+C$$

and we have :
$$G(x)=\int \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x^2}+1}{\left({x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}\right)^2+2+2\sqrt{3}}dx$$
Let $u:=x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}$
$$G(x)=\int \frac{du}{u^2+2+2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{3}}}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{u}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{3}}}}\right)+C$$
Therfore:
$$G(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{3}}}\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{x}}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{3}}}}\right)+C$$

Comment: Finesse! The same technique applies to integrating $\frac{1}{ax^4+bx^2+c}$ in general.